# Iterate two lists and update value on matching element

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class Car
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string? InternalRef {get; set;}
}

var list1 = new List<Car>();
list1.Add(new Car{ Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc"});
list1.Add(new Car{ Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg"});
list1.Add(new Car{ Id = 3, Name = "Seat" });

var list2 = new List<Car>();
list2.Add(new Car{ Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc"});
list2.Add(new Car{ Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg"});
list2.Add(new Car{ Id = 3, Name = "Seat", InternalRef = "xvc" });
```

I want to iterate both lists and:

1. find all members exists with same id
2. set `InternalRef` value from `list2` member to the matching `list1` member where `InternalRef` is null.

`var combined = (from c in list1 where list2.Any(x => c.Id == x.Id) select c).ToList();`

> This will give me a combined list for all members with the same Id, but I still need a way to set InternalRef value

Comment: Do we know roughly what the time complexity of your current linq solution is?

Comment: You don't need to reference to my linq solution. For the info we speak in terms of thousands of objects in each list.

Comment: RTF is asking if you know the time complexity of the algorithm you presented (the `var combined = ...` line). Time complexity loosely means the "efficiency" of your algorithm (it's more complicated than that; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). It appears to be roughly O(n^2) if both lists are roughly equivalent in length.

Comment: a O(nlogn) solution should be feasible for this particular problem (I suppose some sort of hash map or balanced BST?). we are dealing with thousands of objects so that's gonna speed up the runtime by a huge margin

Comment: @JamieNguyen Yeah that's true, I suppose it's starting to get up there in terms of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume the lists are sorted by `Id` as in your example code then you could use binary search to find matches between lists and set `InternalRef` where null rather quickly.

```
var list1 = new List<Car>();
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc" });
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg" });
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 3, Name = "Seat" });

var list2 = new List<Car>();
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc" });
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg" });
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 3, Name = "Seat", InternalRef = "xvc" });


var comparer = new MyComparer();    
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++)
{
    var car = list1[i];
    int index = list2.BinarySearch(car, comparer);  
    
    if (index > 0 && car.InternalRef is null)
    {
        car.InternalRef = list2[index].InternalRef;
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? InternalRef { get; set; }
}

public class MyComparer : Comparer<Car>
{
    public override int Compare(Car x, Car y) => x.Id.CompareTo(y.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to combine each matching element with LINQ and then set the value, why don't you just iterate `list1` and then, if the car is missing the value, you can look it up in the second list:

```cs
// Setup
var list1 = new List<Car>();
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc" });
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg" });
list1.Add(new Car { Id = 3, Name = "Seat" });

var list2 = new List<Car>();
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 1, Name = "Audi", InternalRef = "abc" });
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 2, Name = "Toyota", InternalRef = "dfg" });
list2.Add(new Car { Id = 3, Name = "Seat", InternalRef = "xvc" });

// Actual code
foreach (var car in list1) {
    car.InternalRef ??= list2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == car.Id)?.InternalRef;
}
```

Edit to add to the discussion about time complexity in the post comments: this will have a similar worst-case time complexity as your current algorithm, but in practice will be more efficient because we're only doing a lookup in `list2` for those elements of `list1` that don't have an `InternalRef`. So we greatly reduce the number of lookups we need to do if most elements in `list1` already have an `InternalRef`.